# What is wrong with the handlebar code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, pug

Hey so I am trying to switch from underscore to handlebar, but nothing is rendering from the model, but the templates are changing correctly. Also, when the editTemplate shows from clicking the edit button the #{firstName} and others show as undefined.

In my layout jade file I do include all the appropriate files, jquery, underscore,backbone and handlebar.

Here is my main.js file

```
(function () {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
       // Templates: {},
        Router: {}

    };

    // MODEL
    App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            firstName: 'first',
            lastName: 'last',
            email: 'Email',
            phone: '222',
            birthday: 'date'
        },

        validate: function (attrs) {
            if (!attrs.firstName) {
                return 'You must enter a real first name.';
            }
            if (!attrs.lastName) {
                return 'You must enter a real last name.';
            }
            if (attrs.email.length < 5) {
                return 'You must enter a real email.';
            }
            if (attrs.phone.length < 10 && attrs.phone === int) {
                return 'You must enter a real phone number, if you did please remove the dash and spaces.';
            }
            if (attrs.city.length < 2) {
                return 'You must enter a real city.';
            }
        },

        initialize: function() {
             this.on('invalid', function (model, invalid) {
                console.log(invalid);
            });
        }

    });



    //VIEW
    App.Views.User = Backbone.View.extend({
        model: App.Models.User,
        el: 'user',
        //tagName: 'div',
        //id: 'user',
        //className: 'userProfile',


        initialize: function (){

        },

        render: function() {
            var template = Handlebars.compile($("#userTemplate").html());
            var editTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#userEditTemplate").html());

            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

        events: {
            'click button.edit': 'editProfile',
        //  'click button.save': 'saveEdits',
            'click button.cancel': 'cancelEdits'
        },

        editProfile: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.editTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));

        }, 


        cancelEdits: function() {
            this.render();
        }

    });
    //start history service
    Backbone.history.start();

    var user = new App.Views.User({model: new App.Models.User()});
    user.render();
})();
```

Here is my jade file

```
extends layout
block content   
    div.centerContent
        script(type="text/javascript", src="/js/main.js")

        h4 User goes here with equal before it no space
            div#user
                p #{firstName} #{lastName}
                p #{email}
                p #{phone}
                p #{birthday}
                button.edit Edit



        script(id="userTemplate", type ="text/template")
                p #{firstName} #{lastName}
                p #{email}
                p #{phone}
                p #{birthday}
                button.edit Edit

        script(id="userEditTemplate", type ="text/template")
            div
                form(action="#")
                    input(type="text", class="firstName", value=#{firstName}) input(type="text", class="lastName", value=#{lastName})
                    input(type="email", class="email", value=#{email})
                    input(type="number", class="phone", value=#{phone})
                    input(type="date", class="birthday", value=#{birthday})
                button.save Save
                button.cancel Cancel
        hr
```

layout jade file

```
doctype 5
html
    head
        title=title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css', type='text/css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/bootstrap-responsive.css')
        link(href='/css/bootstrap.css', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
        link(href='/css/font-awesome.min.css', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
        script(src='/js/jquery.min.js', type='text/javascript')
        script(src='/js/jquery.validate.min.js', type='text/javascript')
        script(src='/js/script.js', type='text/javascript')
        script(src='/js/underscore.min.js', type='text/javascript')
        script(src='/js/backbone.min.js', type='text/javascript')
        script(src='/js/handlebars.js', type='text/javascript')
    body
        div#container
            div#header
            block content 
            include footer
```

Comment: If your JavaScript is imported in the head of the page before the DOM is built, those references to the templates won't be satisfied.

Comment: I moved the script main.js file to be loaded at the bottom and it is now just not rendering, but I do not see any errors?

Comment: `el: 'user'` doesn't mean what you think it does, that selector would be looking for a `<user>` element...

Comment: Ok I changed it to div but nothing is being rendered still? Am I missing something? It is like the #{email} and the other ones are just blank

Comment: Try to place your self executing function in $(function(){}). Maybe your template can't get $("#userTemplate").html() properly.

Comment: yeah adding the $ infront actually creates an error.

Comment: It has to be something with the model, because it is not rendering the data from the model but it is changing templates... I have no clue what is wrong with the model tho

Comment: What is `script.js`? Does it rely on underscore, backbone, or handlebars?

Comment: Where is `this.$el` defined? I'm not very familiar with backbone, is this something that backbone defines?

Comment: script.js is actually not running anything. this.$el refers to the element stored in el. Without the $ sign an error is thrown up about the html

Comment: Figured it out, it was just that I was using #{firstName} instead I had to use {{firstName}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wanted to see the answer, it was basically a mistake of calling this

```
#{firstName}
```

instead of the correct usage being:

```
{{firstName}}
```